# Doctrine Extensions - Loggable

Tags: php, symfony, logging, doctrine-orm, deserialization

So I've successfully setup the bundle [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) and have got my entity setup as below:

### Products.orm.yml

```
ACME\DemoBundle\Entity\Product:
type: entity
table: Product
gedmo:
  loggable: true

id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:

#Some other fields#

       cost:
         type: decimal
         presision: 10
         scale: 4
       nullable: true
       gedmo:
          - versioned
```

Which stores in the database all fine and well adding rows to the 'ext_log_entries' table. However the field holding the data I need looks like this:

```
a:1:{s:4:"cost";d:14.9499999;}
```

Now I'm hazarding a guess at this being 'serialized data'? But how do I make use of it?
What I need is just the figure 14.95 as I wish to use the numbers to make price change graphs.
Is it either possible to make the bundle save logs instead of using the 'Data' column have a 'Cost' column only containing the cost figure? Or do I need to somehow extract the data required... if so, how would I go about it?

Any help much appreciated.
Doug.

Comment: `json_encode(array('cost', $entity->getCost())` if your DB column would hold a serialized array it would be very hard for you to filter/select individuel columns by cost... always store plain values in your database. (with very few exception - and only when there is good reason for it)

Comment: That's what I have always thought, read and believed but after installing the Doctrine2 Extensions bundle and made my fields loggable, the above is how it is then stored in the field. I think I am just going to have to fashion my own process instead of relying on other bundles as there doesn't seem to be any support related to this specific feature... I even got a Tumbleweed badge for this question. Hah. Thank-you anyway :)

Comment: in your entity or in the history table? the current version is always in your entity, you can get the changes via `$logs = $repo->getLogEntries($article);` see bottom of https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md